# SQL avoid calling same function twice in select statement

Tags: oracle, function, select

I have a select statement calling same function two times for returning two different columns, Since the same function is called twice, it's creating a performance issue.

I want to call function only once and copy its value to another column. Is it possible in oracle ?

```
SELECT ID
    ,PKGRESTFUNCTION.getBlock(table.ID, table.TYPE) "BLOCK" 
    ,PKGRESTFUNCTION.getBlock(table.ID, table.TYPE) "MASK"
    from table 
    where ID=condition;
```

Comment: One option to consider is to add `RESULT_CACHE` to the function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [with clause](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/with-clause) to get data once

```
with block as (
select PKGRESTFUNCTION.getBlock(table.ID, table.TYPE) as block 
from table
 where ID=condition;
) select ID, block.block as "BLOCK" , block.block as "MASK" from block
```

> The WITH clause, or subquery factoring clause, is part of the SQL-99 standard and was added into the Oracle SQL syntax in Oracle 9.2. The WITH clause may be processed as an inline view or resolved as a temporary table. The advantage of the latter is that repeated references to the subquery may be more efficient as **the data is easily retrieved from the temporary table, rather than being requeried by each reference**. You should assess the performance implications of the WITH clause on a case-by-case basis.